# Problemas al leer un json y guardar información | Angular, Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, angular, base-de-datos, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo un esquema de datos `json` como este:

```
{
   "schemas":{
      "Nike":{
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "Nombre":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "talla":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "link_articulo":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "fecha_envio":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Converse":{
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "anio":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "fabrica":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "marca":{
               "type":"string"
            }"item":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "vans":{
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "nombre":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "fecha_cierre":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "codigo":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Adidas":{
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "fecha_emision":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "lugar_emision":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "denominacion":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Tengo un servicio en `Angular` donde accedo a `schemas` luego a la llave del objeto que sigue `Nike`, `Converse`... así sucesivamente, guardo está información mandando un post a mi servidor y guardó en una tabla de la `DB`, luego accedo a `properties` de cada una de las marcas y guardo en otra tabla de la `DB` estas propiedades.

Tengo un método donde lee constantemente el `json`

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_ESQUEMA);
}
```

Logro controlar que si se agrega una propiedad, por ejemplo si a `Nike` se le añade `fecha_cierre` se inserta en la base de datos solo la nueva propiedad en este caso `fecha_cierre` y en las demás marcas no se agrega nada, esto lo hago en mi servidor hecho en `django rest framework` en mi `models.py` en `unique_together = ["marca", "propiedad"]`:

```
class Configuracion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    propiedad = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["marca", "propiedad"] 
        db_table = 'configuracion'
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es que si se borra una propiedad del esquema de información `json` por ejemplo si de `Converse` se elimina de `properties` la propiedad `fabrica` no sé como hacer que solo se elimine ese registro en mi `DB`. La solución que se me ocurre es borrar todo de la base de datos y volver a recorrer y guardar el esquema. O cómo lo puedo hacer? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es posible cambiar la estructura de tu schema? De manera que no sean propiedades anidadas, si no más bien un arreglo? Así estandarizas el json y puedes agregar de manera dinámica más propiedades.